# Duplicate jquery when using unobtrusiveValidationMode

Tags: c#, validation, webforms, .net-4.5

When using the unobtrusivevalidationmode on a page that already has jquery on it, jquery is loaded twice. Once in the header, once just inside the form. How do you prevent this from occurring.

Comment: How are you adding jQuery to the page? Directly in the HTML, using `RegisterClientScriptInclude` ... ?

Comment: I have tried directly in HTML, I have tried registering it in a script manager, and I have tried using the RegisterClientScriptInclude.